# CSS different background on title's siblings odd and even

Tags: html, css

I am trying to customize css in wordpress article. So all elements are following each other in the same container as below example.

I would like to apply a background color on all elements after `h3` even (red) or odd (white) different.

But the problem is from the moment I have 3 titles, it is breacking as below and all go red. As I have more than 1000 articles, I cannot just go and mofify the structure of each article manualy.

```css
article > h3:nth-of-type(odd), article > h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ :not(h3){
    background:white;
}

article > h3:nth-of-type(even), article > h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ :not(h3){
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>The 9 Months 2020 Market Stands Robust vs 12/2019</h3>
  <p><a href="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse.png" class="customize-unpreviewable"><img class="alignleft  wp-image-27532" src="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse-300x154.png" alt="Project Smart Explorer Database" width="189" height="97" srcset="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse-300x154.png 300w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse.png 525w" sizes="(max-width: 189px) 100vw, 189px"></a>Surprisingly, the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/upstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Oil &amp; Gas</a></strong> and <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Petrochemical</a></strong> Market stands robust after <strong>9 months 2020</strong> compared with the <strong>12 months of 2019</strong>.</p>
  <p>This statement refers to the volume in <strong>US$</strong> of <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/barrel-price-and-covid-19-impact-on-oil-gas-and-petrochemicals/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">engineering, procurement and construction (EPC)</a></strong> contracts awarded by operators to contractors on respective periods.</p>
  <p>This information comes from all the projects above <strong>$100 million</strong> capital expenditure (Capex) through the database <strong><a href="https://projectsmartexplorer.com/" class="customize-unpreviewable">www.projectsmartexplorer.com</a></strong>.</p>
  <p>From this database, the barre graph below shows the volume of Capex sanctioned to contractors year per year.</p>
  <figure id="attachment_29100" aria-describedby="caption-attachment-29100" style="width: 583px" class="wp-caption aligncenter"><a href="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Oil-Gas-and-Petrochemical-Capital-Expenditure-per-Year-on-September-2020.png" class="customize-unpreviewable"><img class=" wp-image-29100" src="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Oil-Gas-and-Petrochemical-Capital-Expenditure-per-Year-on-September-2020.png" alt="Oil &amp; Gas and Petrochemical Capital Expenditure 9 Months 2020" width="583" height="216" srcset="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Oil-Gas-and-Petrochemical-Capital-Expenditure-per-Year-on-September-2020.png 810w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Oil-Gas-and-Petrochemical-Capital-Expenditure-per-Year-on-September-2020-300x111.png 300w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Oil-Gas-and-Petrochemical-Capital-Expenditure-per-Year-on-September-2020-768x284.png 768w" sizes="(max-width: 583px) 100vw, 583px" style="
      /* height: auto; */
  "></a><figcaption id="caption-attachment-29100" class="wp-caption-text">Oil &amp; Gas and Petrochemical Capital Expenditure 9 Months 2020</figcaption></figure>
  <p>Therefore, this barre graph reports actual figures of Capex, not forecast.</p>
  <p>Until <strong>2019</strong>, they cover <strong>12 months</strong> per year, while in <strong>2020</strong> and beyond, they address the situation at the end of September, so <strong>9 months</strong> only.</p>
  <p>As a result, the <strong>Q3</strong> market dynamic confirms <strong>Q2</strong> as the <strong>9 months</strong> Capex <strong>2020</strong> represent <strong>93%</strong> of the <strong>12 months 2019</strong>.</p>
  <h3>National and Independent Companies still Bullish</h3>
  <p>While all the medias reported bad news since the Covid crisis and the barrel price war, how can the market by that dynamic?</p>
  <p>The picture below represents the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/upstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Oil &amp; Gas</a></strong> and <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Petrochemical</a></strong> Capex forecasted on the next<strong> 5 years</strong> split&nbsp; according to the operator profile.</p>
  <figure id="attachment_29108" aria-describedby="caption-attachment-29108" style="width: 573px" class="wp-caption aligncenter"><a href="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/IOC-NOC-Independent-Companies-Market-Split-on-September-2020.png" class="customize-unpreviewable"><img class="size-full wp-image-29108" src="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/IOC-NOC-Independent-Companies-Market-Split-on-September-2020.png" alt="" width="573" height="382" srcset="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/IOC-NOC-Independent-Companies-Market-Split-on-September-2020.png 573w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/IOC-NOC-Independent-Companies-Market-Split-on-September-2020-300x200.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 573px) 100vw, 573px"></a><figcaption id="caption-attachment-29108" class="wp-caption-text">Market split between IOC, NOC and Independent Companies on September 2020</figcaption></figure>
  <p>The <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">national oil companies (NOCs)</a></strong>, in red, lead the game with <strong>54%</strong> market share.</p>
  <p>The <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/independent-definition/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">independent companies (Independents)</a></strong>, in green, show good resilience at <strong>30%</strong>.</p>
  <p>The <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/ioc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">international oil companies (IOCs)</a></strong>, in blue, lag behind at <strong>17%</strong>.</p>
  <p>Only six months ago, the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/ioc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">IOCs</a></strong> were still at <strong>20%</strong> and the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> at <strong>51%</strong>.</p>
  <p>This market shift trend from <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/ioc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">IOCs</a></strong> to <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> and Independents started after the first barrel price crash in <strong>2014</strong>. But it accelerated with the Covid-19.</p>
  <p>While <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/ioc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">IOCs</a></strong> cut again expenditures, <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> increased them again and <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/independent-definition/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Independents</a></strong> maintained them.</p>
  <h3>National Companies become Dominant</h3>
  <p>In exceeding <strong>53%</strong> market share the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> become de facto dominant.</p>
  <p>In fact, conjunctural and structural reasons explain <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> policy:</p>
  <ol>
  <li><strong>The local role of central banks</strong><br>On each crisis, the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> behave as central banks.<br>They have the capability to borrow money on international financial markets to irrigate the local economy through investments.</li>
  <li><strong>They play opportunism</strong><br>In tendering projects while <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/ioc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">IOCs</a></strong> turn down, they expect lower prices for their projects.</li>
  <li><strong>Restore market shares</strong><br>OPEC members have easier to restore their crude oil market share from <strong>32%</strong> to <strong>40%</strong> and preserve their regulating power.</li>
  <li><strong>Balance Upstream and Downstream</strong><br>High barrel price favors <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/upstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Upstream</a></strong> activities.<br>While low price gives the opportunity to <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> to increase <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Downstream</a></strong> sector.</li>
  <li><strong>Downstream is strategic for manufacturing</strong><br>Most of the producing countries face a demographic and employment challenges.<br>In practice, it means more local goods production whereas <a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">refining</a> and <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Petrochemical</a></strong> are first source of supply.&nbsp;</li>
  </ol>
  <p>In conclusion, all these reasons explain the current market dynamic. They open excellent perspectives for <strong>2020</strong> to exceed <strong>2019</strong> and to continue on coming years.</p>
  <p>As <strong>Saudis</strong> say: “Don’t waste a crisis”.</p>
  <p style="text-align: center;">And o<span lang="en">f course, you can count on&nbsp;<strong>Project Smart Explorer&nbsp;</strong></span><span lang="en">to guide you on these projects:&nbsp;</span><strong><a href="https://www.projectsmartexplorer.com/" class="customize-unpreviewable">www.projectsmartexplorer.com</a></strong></p>
  <p style="text-align: center;">To get&nbsp;<strong>regular news about the Energy market and the digitalization</strong>,<br>you can subscribe to our newsletter at this&nbsp;<a href="http://site2b1st.local/newsletter/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">link</a></p>
  <p><a href="https://projectsmartexplorer.com" class="customize-unpreviewable"><img class="aligncenter  wp-image-27532" src="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse.png" alt="Project Smart Explorer Database" width="260" height="134" srcset="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse.png 525w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse-300x154.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 260px) 100vw, 260px"></a></p>
</article>
```

Comment: `h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ :not(h3)` will also apply to odd elements (excepy h3) after the first even... its like you want the styles to start and then stop, then start and stop again

Comment: @zgood I understood that, but how to solve was tricky, but made it. Check my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem with the css below, if someone finds better, let me know:

```css
/* For odd */
h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ h3:nth-of-type(odd),
h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ *

/* For even */
h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ h3:nth-of-type(even),
h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ *
```

The logic is to repeat as much as you can the loop above to be sure it is covering a maximum of repetition. So you set even and odd following.
Logic is like to set :

```
├── h3:nth-of-type(even)
├── h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ *
│    ├── h3:nth-of-type(odd)
│    ├── h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ *
│    │   ├── h3:nth-of-type(even)
│    │   ├── h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ *
```

DEMO:

```css
article > h3:nth-of-type(odd),
article > h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ *,
article > h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ h3:nth-of-type(odd),
article > h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ *{
    background:orange;
}

article > h3:nth-of-type(even),
article > h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ *,
article > h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ h3:nth-of-type(even),
article > h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ h3:nth-of-type(odd) ~ h3:nth-of-type(even) ~ *{
    background:red;
}

article * {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>The 9 Months 2020 Market Stands Robust vs 12/2019</h3>
  <p><a href="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse.png" class="customize-unpreviewable"><img class="alignleft  wp-image-27532" src="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse-300x154.png" alt="Project Smart Explorer Database" width="189" height="97" srcset="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse-300x154.png 300w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse.png 525w" sizes="(max-width: 189px) 100vw, 189px"></a>Surprisingly, the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/upstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Oil &amp; Gas</a></strong> and <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Petrochemical</a></strong> Market stands robust after <strong>9 months 2020</strong> compared with the <strong>12 months of 2019</strong>.</p>
  <p>This statement refers to the volume in <strong>US$</strong> of <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/barrel-price-and-covid-19-impact-on-oil-gas-and-petrochemicals/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">engineering, procurement and construction (EPC)</a></strong> contracts awarded by operators to contractors on respective periods.</p>
  <p>This information comes from all the projects above <strong>$100 million</strong> capital expenditure (Capex) through the database <strong><a href="https://projectsmartexplorer.com/" class="customize-unpreviewable">www.projectsmartexplorer.com</a></strong>.</p>
  <p>From this database, the barre graph below shows the volume of Capex sanctioned to contractors year per year.</p>
  <figure id="attachment_29100" aria-describedby="caption-attachment-29100" style="width: 583px" class="wp-caption aligncenter"><a href="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Oil-Gas-and-Petrochemical-Capital-Expenditure-per-Year-on-September-2020.png" class="customize-unpreviewable"><img class=" wp-image-29100" src="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Oil-Gas-and-Petrochemical-Capital-Expenditure-per-Year-on-September-2020.png" alt="Oil &amp; Gas and Petrochemical Capital Expenditure 9 Months 2020" width="583" height="216" srcset="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Oil-Gas-and-Petrochemical-Capital-Expenditure-per-Year-on-September-2020.png 810w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Oil-Gas-and-Petrochemical-Capital-Expenditure-per-Year-on-September-2020-300x111.png 300w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Oil-Gas-and-Petrochemical-Capital-Expenditure-per-Year-on-September-2020-768x284.png 768w" sizes="(max-width: 583px) 100vw, 583px" style="
      /* height: auto; */
  "></a><figcaption id="caption-attachment-29100" class="wp-caption-text">Oil &amp; Gas and Petrochemical Capital Expenditure 9 Months 2020</figcaption></figure>
  <p>Therefore, this barre graph reports actual figures of Capex, not forecast.</p>
  <p>Until <strong>2019</strong>, they cover <strong>12 months</strong> per year, while in <strong>2020</strong> and beyond, they address the situation at the end of September, so <strong>9 months</strong> only.</p>
  <p>As a result, the <strong>Q3</strong> market dynamic confirms <strong>Q2</strong> as the <strong>9 months</strong> Capex <strong>2020</strong> represent <strong>93%</strong> of the <strong>12 months 2019</strong>.</p>
  <h3>National and Independent Companies still Bullish</h3>
  <p>While all the medias reported bad news since the Covid crisis and the barrel price war, how can the market by that dynamic?</p>
  <p>The picture below represents the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/upstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Oil &amp; Gas</a></strong> and <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Petrochemical</a></strong> Capex forecasted on the next<strong> 5 years</strong> split&nbsp; according to the operator profile.</p>
  <figure id="attachment_29108" aria-describedby="caption-attachment-29108" style="width: 573px" class="wp-caption aligncenter"><a href="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/IOC-NOC-Independent-Companies-Market-Split-on-September-2020.png" class="customize-unpreviewable"><img class="size-full wp-image-29108" src="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/IOC-NOC-Independent-Companies-Market-Split-on-September-2020.png" alt="" width="573" height="382" srcset="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/IOC-NOC-Independent-Companies-Market-Split-on-September-2020.png 573w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/IOC-NOC-Independent-Companies-Market-Split-on-September-2020-300x200.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 573px) 100vw, 573px"></a><figcaption id="caption-attachment-29108" class="wp-caption-text">Market split between IOC, NOC and Independent Companies on September 2020</figcaption></figure>
  <p>The <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">national oil companies (NOCs)</a></strong>, in red, lead the game with <strong>54%</strong> market share.</p>
  <p>The <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/independent-definition/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">independent companies (Independents)</a></strong>, in green, show good resilience at <strong>30%</strong>.</p>
  <p>The <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/ioc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">international oil companies (IOCs)</a></strong>, in blue, lag behind at <strong>17%</strong>.</p>
  <p>Only six months ago, the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/ioc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">IOCs</a></strong> were still at <strong>20%</strong> and the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> at <strong>51%</strong>.</p>
  <p>This market shift trend from <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/ioc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">IOCs</a></strong> to <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> and Independents started after the first barrel price crash in <strong>2014</strong>. But it accelerated with the Covid-19.</p>
  <p>While <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/ioc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">IOCs</a></strong> cut again expenditures, <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> increased them again and <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/independent-definition/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Independents</a></strong> maintained them.</p>
  <h3>National Companies become Dominant</h3>
  <p>In exceeding <strong>53%</strong> market share the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> become de facto dominant.</p>
  <p>In fact, conjunctural and structural reasons explain <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> policy:</p>
  <ol>
  <li><strong>The local role of central banks</strong><br>On each crisis, the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> behave as central banks.<br>They have the capability to borrow money on international financial markets to irrigate the local economy through investments.</li>
  <li><strong>They play opportunism</strong><br>In tendering projects while <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/ioc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">IOCs</a></strong> turn down, they expect lower prices for their projects.</li>
  <li><strong>Restore market shares</strong><br>OPEC members have easier to restore their crude oil market share from <strong>32%</strong> to <strong>40%</strong> and preserve their regulating power.</li>
  <li><strong>Balance Upstream and Downstream</strong><br>High barrel price favors <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/upstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Upstream</a></strong> activities.<br>While low price gives the opportunity to <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/noc/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">NOCs</a></strong> to increase <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Downstream</a></strong> sector.</li>
  <li><strong>Downstream is strategic for manufacturing</strong><br>Most of the producing countries face a demographic and employment challenges.<br>In practice, it means more local goods production whereas <a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">refining</a> and <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Petrochemical</a></strong> are first source of supply.&nbsp;</li>
  </ol>
  <p>In conclusion, all these reasons explain the current market dynamic. They open excellent perspectives for <strong>2020</strong> to exceed <strong>2019</strong> and to continue on coming years.</p>
  <p>As <strong>Saudis</strong> say: “Don’t waste a crisis”.</p>
  <p style="text-align: center;">And o<span lang="en">f course, you can count on&nbsp;<strong>Project Smart Explorer&nbsp;</strong></span><span lang="en">to guide you on these projects:&nbsp;</span><strong><a href="https://www.projectsmartexplorer.com/" class="customize-unpreviewable">www.projectsmartexplorer.com</a></strong></p>
  <p style="text-align: center;">To get&nbsp;<strong>regular news about the Energy market and the digitalization</strong>,<br>you can subscribe to our newsletter at this&nbsp;<a href="http://site2b1st.local/newsletter/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">link</a></p>
  <p><a href="https://projectsmartexplorer.com" class="customize-unpreviewable"><img class="aligncenter  wp-image-27532" src="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse.png" alt="Project Smart Explorer Database" width="260" height="134" srcset="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse.png 525w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse-300x154.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 260px) 100vw, 260px"></a></p>
  <h3>The 9 Months 2020 Market Stands Robust vs 12/2019</h3>
  <p><a href="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse.png" class="customize-unpreviewable"><img class="alignleft  wp-image-27532" src="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse-300x154.png" alt="Project Smart Explorer Database" width="189" height="97" srcset="http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse-300x154.png 300w, http://site2b1st.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/pse.png 525w" sizes="(max-width: 189px) 100vw, 189px"></a>Surprisingly, the <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/upstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Oil &amp; Gas</a></strong> and <strong><a href="http://site2b1st.local/downstream/?customize_changeset_uuid=1a2d80b2-5fd3-4dc6-9f7f-a165b290f568&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on">Petrochemical</a></strong> Market stands robust after <strong>9 months 2020</strong> compared with the <strong>12 months of 2019</strong>.</p>
</article>
```